# validating xml in ssis - memory problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am validating a xml with xsd in a SSIS package. i have a 1GB file, while validating that the memory consumption is going upto 3.5 gb. Is there anyway we can validate xml using xsd in SSIS with lesser memory (with c# validation or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Wil, Posting the steps that i did, believe this may help someone

1. Created a script task, do the validation there (use xmlreader settings)
2. Fail the script task, if the validation fails
3. If task pass, execute the xml source task inside data flow and store it

Answer (score 1):

SSIS loads the entire file into memory, so the memory consumption on the file is unavoidable. You could create an XML SCHEMA COLLECTION that recreates your XSD, assign that to an XML column in a table, and attempt to load the file into the table:

1. Create an XML SCHEMA COLLECTION with the format of your XSD.
2. Create your table with the XML column specifying the schema
3. Attempt to load the XML file into the table using SSIS.

You can see an example of how to create the schema collection and create the table here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx

Comment: If the xsd changes by time we need to recreate the table again and again isn't it. And can you please tell me, is this approach memory efficient.

Comment: You do not need to create the table again and again, the XML column just attempts to contain the XML validated by the schema. If your XSD is changing, then you'll need to recreate the XML SCHEMA COLLECTION but that's unavoidable. This method would be more memory efficient than using SSIS because the entire file won't be loaded into memory, it would be bulk-loaded to the table. Otherwise, your only option is some kind of C# xsd validation function.